# Mapping NSManagedObject Entity to custom class with RestKit

Tags: json, core-data, restkit

I am able to pull JSON results and map them to the db. However, as soon as I try and map the entity to my subclass, it seems that my mapping breaks.

```
JSON Sample:
{"Customers":[{"Customer":{"Active":"Y","BranchID":0,"CustomerID":"SMCJIMB00736253","CustomerIdentifier":"","CustomerTypeID":0,"Name":""}}]}

Setup:
// Initialize RestKit
RKObjectManager* objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:TEST_SERVICES_ROOT];

// Initialize object store
objectManager.objectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore objectStoreWithStoreFilename:RKDefaultSeedDatabaseFileName];

Mapping:
RKManagedObjectMapping* customerMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Customer class]];
customerMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"customerID";
[customerMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:@"Active", @"active", nil];
[customerMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:@"BranchID", @"branchID", nil];
[customerMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:@"CustomerID", @"customerID", nil];
[customerMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:@"CustomerIdentifier", @"customerIdentifier", nil];
[customerMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:@"CustomerTypeID", @"customerTypeID", nil];
[customerMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:@"Name", @"name", nil];

Add Mapping:
[objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:customerMapping forKeyPath:@"Customers.Customer"];

Call WS:
// Load the object model via RestKit    
RKObjectManager* objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:SERVICE_CUSTOMERS,@"0",@"1",@"100"];
[objectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:url delegate:self block:^(RKObjectLoader* loader) {
    loader.objectMapping = [objectManager.mappingProvider objectMappingForClass:[Customer class]];
}];

@interface Customer : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* active;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* branchID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* customerID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* customerIdentifier;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* customerTypeID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* name;

//populated via fetch predicate
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* customerAddress;

@end

@implementation Customer

@dynamic active;
@dynamic branchID;
@dynamic customerID;
@dynamic customerIdentifier;
@dynamic customerTypeID;
@dynamic name;

//populated via fetch predicate
@dynamic customerAddress;

@end
```

This works fine as long as I don't try and map the Customer class to the Entity in the data model. Ultimately, I am trying to use my Customer class as a MKAnnotation, but I can't since I cant provide a concrete implementation class. I'm sure that there is some sort of misunderstanding of RestKit to blame. I see that the RKTwitterCoreData has the RKStatus as a concrete subclass.

@end

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
   I figured it out after much trial and error! The issue was that I needed to set my rootKeyPath on my mapping to match the rootkeyPath that I use when I added the mapping to the mapping provider. The RKTwitterCoreData client does not do this, but I needed to for whatever reason.

```
    RKManagedObjectMapping* userMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[User class]];
    userMapping.rootKeyPath = @"User";
    userMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"userName";
    [userMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:@"Authenticated", @"authenticated", nil];

    ................
    [objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:userMapping forKeyPath:@"User"];
```